# torch.max() also does the job of torch.maximum()?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

**Definition wise**: `max()` function should output the maximum element present in the array (in NumPy context) or tensor (in PyTorch context). Whereas, `maximum()` is used for comparison between two arrays or tensors. Same goes for `min()` and `minimum()`.

---

With NumPy the definition is followed and even you'll get an error when you do comparison using `max()` function, but this is not consistent with PyTorch. So this creates a confusion when one wants to change the codebase from [**PyTorch**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.max.html)[pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch) to [**NumPy**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.max.html)[numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) :(

A Simple example to illustrate what's going on:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[ 0., 10.],
              [10., 20.],
              [32., 38.]])
B = np.array([[ 0., 20.],
              [ 0., 19.],
              [10., 20.]])
np.max(A, B)
```

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

And this (above in *spoiler blockquote*) should be the output for `torch.max()` as well. But:

```py
import torch
A = torch.FloatTensor([[ 0., 10.],
                       [10., 20.],
                       [32., 38.]])
B = torch.FloatTensor([[ 0., 20.],
                       [ 0., 19.],
                       [10., 20.]])
torch.max(A, B)
```

> tensor([[ 0., 20.], [10., 20.], [32., 38.]])

Whereas with `torch.maximum()` again this is the same output (which suggest, the `torch.maximum()` should be deprecated!)

```py
print(torch.maximum(A, B))
```

> tensor([[ 0., 20.], [10., 20.], [32., 38.]])

So a request to [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch) maintainers to reset this over-featuring in `torch.max()` function :pray:

Comment: I agree with you, but maybe it is better to ask your request not on stackoverflow but at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch. The [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.max.html) does report both features of torch.max.